# Convert DOM Node to String without using javax.* classes

Tags: java, javascript, xml, rhino, java-5

When I'm trying to use found solutions to convert from Node to String in javascript, starting from this line

```
var transformer = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
```

it says

> Message:  (Desired evaluation could not be performed: JavaScript
>   Error: Internal Error: ReferenceError: "javax" is not defined.
>   (JavaScript Error: Internal Error: ReferenceError: "javax" is not
>   defined.)

but classes from java* package work OK

this works:

```
var writer = new java.io.StringWriter();
```

Is it possible to convert `Node` to `String` without using classes from javax* package?

using org.w3c.* is ok though

Comment: What are you trying to do? You should write a helper class that does the XML handling for you and bind an instance of that to your scriptengine.

Comment: @mwhs I'm working in system which allows to write java code in javascript (new in javascript, maybe it's common to write Java inside js). Some API method from the system returns DOM Node instance and I need to convert it to String using Java language in javascript. That javascript "engine" seems like doesn't support javax package and I don't have access to link package or custom written /*jar//*class files. I need to convert that Node to String using classes from java* package

Comment: @VextoR `myNode.outerHTML`

Comment: I think this is a misconception. You are actually writing javascript, but some of the java classes have been bound to your javascript engine with their full name. There is no keyword `var` in java. Maybe you should tell us the name of your system.

Comment: @mwhs probably you're right. In any case I would love to convert that Node to String using "Java" or javascript. It doesn't matter which to use. System name is "Progress Sonic ESB 7.6"

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot extend the binding context of your javascript execution environment?

Comment: I am pretty sure that Progress Sonic ESB internally uses Rhino as its JavaScript engine. I've updated the question's tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonic ESB internally uses Rhino as its JavaScript engine.

When calling Java from JavaScript, you should reference the Java classes using `Packages`: `Packages.javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`
The reason you can use the java packages without trouble is that `Packages.java` has been aliased in the global variable `java`.

When you do this, you can use the classes in the `javax` package just fine. In fact, you can add any jars you like to the classpath and use those classes too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Scripting_Java